# how to use variables

Tags: excel, vba

Doesn't work "A" variables
Am I missing something?

```
Sub title
    Dim A
    A = Cells(20,87).value
    Workbooks("workbook1.xlsx).WorkSheets("5.588"). Range("AQ12:BW26).Copy  _
    Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx).Worksheets("A").Range("A")
End sub
```

Comment: Remove the quotes - i.e. just use `Worksheets(A)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you're working with multiple sheets and workbooks I'd suggest you be as specific as possible with all of your references. I worked up an example using only one workbook and two sheets but you can easily add the workbook references as you are already using the in your code and adjust the ranges as appropriate. You'll also notice the use of .Text vs .Value since you are retrieving a text value for the destination range not a number (value). Also I changed the variable name as you had two references to "A" which can be confusing when you're reading code.

```
Sub title()
    Dim zDest As String
    zDest = Worksheets("5.588").Range("F1").Text
    Worksheets("5.588").Range("A5:B11").Copy (Worksheets("A").Range(zDest))
End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: This does not answer the questions, despite the OP accepting it. The questions were "[H]ow to use variables[?]" and "Am I missing something?" Those two specific questions are not directly answered.

Comment: Yes it does, the use of the quoted A in the .Range was the problem. Changing the variable names was just for clarity but still w/o the quoting.

Comment: Yes, the use of the quoted `"A"` was the problem, but your answer doesn't mention that that. You vaguely mention that you "changed the variable name as you had two references to "A" which can be confusing when you're reading code" but that doesn't specifically say that `"A"` was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the quotes from e.g. `Worksheets(A)`, but add them into Range as follows: e.g. `Range("AQ12:BW26").Copy`.